# É possível criar um mapa para posicionar elementos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Gostaria de saber se é possível "pré-definir" a posição de um elemento ao usar um `append`, por exemplo:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
   <div class="child" data-position="2"></div>
   <div class="child" data-position="6"></div>
   <div class="child" data-position="7"></div>
   <div class="child" data-position="9"></div>
</div>
```

Agora depois de uma determinada ação do usuário digamos que eu precise usar o seguinte `append`:

```
$("#mainDiv").append('<div class="child" data-position="5"></div>');
```

Por padrão o elemento será adicionado ao fim do conteúdo atual da `div#mainDiv`, porém eu gostaria de criar uma função que detecta em qual posição tal elemento deve ser adicionado que no caso seria entre os childs 2 e 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer um `.each()` percorrendo as `div`s verificando o valor em `data-position` de cada elemento.

Quando encontrar um valor maior do que o `data-position` da `div` a ser inserida, o loop é cancelado com `return false;` e o valor do índice do elemento vindo de `(e)` é atribuído à variável `idx`.

No `if` após o loop você usa `.before()` para inserir a `div` antes do elemento de classe `.child` cujo índice está em `idx`.

Caso o loop não tiver encontrado um elemento com `data-position` maior, significa que todas possuem valor em `data-position` menor, logo o valor de `idx` continuará indefinido e a `div` será inserida no final com `.append()`:

```js
function add(div){
   var pos = $(div).data('position'); // pega o valor do data-position
   var idx;
   
   $("#mainDiv .child").each(function(e){
      if($(this).data('position') > pos){
         idx = e; // idx pega o valor do índice encontrado
         return false; // aborta o loop
      }
   });
   
   if(idx >= 0){
      // O ":eq()" seleciona o elemento pelo índice (base zero)
      // No caso, a div com o valor data-position "6" é de índice 1
      $("#mainDiv .child:eq("+idx+")").before(div);
   }else{
     $("#mainDiv").append(div);
   }
}

// chama a função passando a div a ser inserida
add('<div class="child" data-position="5">5</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv">
   <div class="child" data-position="2">2</div>
   <div class="child" data-position="6">6</div>
   <div class="child" data-position="7">7</div>
   <div class="child" data-position="9">9</div>
</div>
```

Há variadas formas de inserir a `div`. Você pode, por exemplo, enviar para a função apenas o número do `data-position` e montar a `div` dentro da função, entre outras.